# Use all of the following symbols and numbers in one equation for the result to be equal to 10

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Use all of the following symbols and numbers in one equation for the result to be equal to 10
(14, 12, 9 , 7, 3) (÷ × - +)

Comment: It doesn't, since his question has two ÷. Mine is one ÷  and the other is +.

Comment: Hi jacob and welcome to Puzzling! Two puzzles in a day with *almost* the same exact puzzle... Is your puzzle inspired by the other or did you find this one somewhere online? If you found it elsewhere please tell us where so we can ensure its creator is credited correctly. Thanks! :)